# Can't set text margin to make it lower

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make my text to make my text lower to make it to the center of the `<div>` tag. But I tried to use `margin-top` to make it lower a little bit but it just can't work. This is my code.

```css
.loremipsum {
    background-color: white;
    height: 1060px;
}
.content {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 75px;
}
.h3 {
    border: 2px black solid;
    width: 750px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loremipsum" id="loremipsum" >
    <div class="h3">
        <h3 class="content" >Why Choose Us?</h3>
    </div>
    <p class="content">We create the best front-end design.Each template cost only $5.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add `padding` to its container?

Comment: Why did you use `jQuery` and `JavaScript` tags?

Comment: @MelanciaUK,padding doesn't work either.

Comment: Anyway... It looks to be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/L87j8kws/

Comment: @MelanciaUK,I know,but it just can't work on my website

Comment: Probably because there are other styles being applied to this element? Did you try to inspect it using your browser dev tools and checking?

Comment: @MelanciaUK,my website run on local server

Comment: @MikeYung: you will still be able to use the dev tools (debug using google chrome, for example)

Comment: @jbutler483,do you ctrl+shift+j?

Comment: Yes, or right click -> inspect element

Comment: You sound clearly lost, I'm afraid. I would honestly recommend you spending some valuable time reading tutorials and other material to give you a starts up before trying to code.

Comment: @jbutler483,@MelanciaUK,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to look up a lot of web based tutorials before you go any further, as web based development is vast (esp for a complete beginner)

I've created a quick demo of margin and padding examples below, (I would post as a comment, although for demonstration purposes, this might be better)

[image]

```css
html{background:gray;}
div {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.right {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.left {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.bottom {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.left-padded{
padding-left:100px;
}
.right-padded{
padding-right:100px;
}
.top-padded{
padding-top:100px;
}
.bottom-padded{
padding-bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">I'm normal</div>
<div class="right">I'm margin-right</div>
<div class="left">I'm margin-left</div>
<div class="top">I'm margin-top</div>
<div class="bottom">I'm margin-bottom</div>
<div class="left-padded">I'm padded-left</div>
<div class="right-padded">I'm padded-right</div>
<div class="top-padded">I'm padded-top</div>
<div class="bottom-padded">I'm padded-bottom</div>
```

Comment: When I check the inspect element,it does not show the style of h3.Instant,it show inherited from body.But I does not write any style for body.

Comment: there's a lot of default styles added by your browser. But go through your page and you'll see elements on the page 'highlighting'. Clicking on the element, and down the right hand side is all styling rules that are currently applied to that element.

Comment: Pretty much, find a h3 element, click on it, and it will show you the styling rules applied.

Comment: I press it.But it show h3 class inherit from body style.But I dont remember I write any style for body.

Comment: That's because in web based dev, children (nested elements) inherit from any and all parents (unless you overwrite these stylings).But as I said, your browser will add its *default* stylings as well.

Comment: But how should I overwrite?

Comment: styling your child elements to what you want. A 'css reset'. Add a class to child and overwrite. These are just some of the options.

Comment: I would love to go through a whole intro into css, but unfortuately I just don't have the free time. The best thing i can do is point you to [this](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-TlhFi/0/1) - which should help you on your way to being a web developer!

Answer (score -1):

You can set property to important. so it will give priority

`

```
 .h3 {
    border: 2px black solid;
    width: 750px;
  margin:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
```

}
h3.content{padding:25px}      `

Check it on fiddle :   `[http://jsfiddle.net/515zttfr/][1]`

Comment: no no and no. Please do not advise new web developers to jump to the use of the **!important** tag.

Comment: Edited answer.add padding to h3 tag